# Modify GridFieldFilterHeader to work with custom summary fields

Tags: silverstripe

To accomplish a nicer output of saved data I often use the output of functions in `$summary_fields` the easiest example for this would be `Created.Nice24` this returns the date in a more readable format but prevents it from being filtered or sorted by this value.

Is there a way to overcome this problem and is it also possible to modify the GridFieldFilterHeader to use those nice values for search and perhaps display a dropdownfield instead of an textfield for input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer your first question: No it's not possible to sort by columns who's date is represented by a function as you describe - this is because the underlying logic is basically a "SORT BY" SQL clause, and a function-name obviously *isn't* a database field.

I honestly don't *know* if the second is possible, but it certainly is for custom fields for a ModelAdmin's centre-pane. You could subclass `GridFieldSortableHeader` and try and modify it to do what you want. Have a squiz at the docs for the `$searchable_fields` static and `DataObject::scaffoldSearchFields()` to see how the CMS itself achieves it.

Comment: is there a way to display the function ouput but use the db field for sorting?

Comment: Out of the box, no I don't think so. But what I was thinking the other day was to lose `$searchable_fields` entirely and use pure JS. A GridField is just an HTML `<table>` so a JS lib could do the sorting client side.

This may be relevant here too: http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/customising-the-cms/show/16563

The only downside being that if edits / deletions to the model(s) being displayed in the GridField happend in the CMS by other CMS users, you wouldn't see the changes data until the next time you reloaded yur browser. Pagination may get a little funky too.

Comment: ok I'll give it a try. I've head a similar though, instead of using js for sorting, perhaps you could use it to change the data to fit the format you need it, but that would be very static.